# Calculate $\int_{0}^{1} (x-f(x))^{2016} dx$, given $f(f(x))=x$.

Tags: definite-integrals

This question was asked in an entrance test for an undergraduate mathematics program today, held all over India.

**Question:** $f$ is a differentiable function in $[0,1]$ such that $f(f(x))=x$ and $f(0)=1$.

Find the value of $\int_{0}^{1} (x-f(x))^{2016} dx$.

I tried to solve it by substituting $f(f(x))$ in place of $x$, but could not proceed much further. Any hints or solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: the obvious function satisfying the conditions is $1-x$.

Comment: Which test was this asked in?

Comment: @Nikunj For ISI - Indian Statistics Institute.

Comment: @almagest Is this operation valid for reaching that conclusion?             If we apply Lagrange's MVT on $f$ which is differentiable in $(0,1)$ & continuous on $[0,1]$, $\exists$ at least one $c$ $\in (0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0}=-1$ [since $f(1)=0$ ]. So one possible function is $f(x)=-x+p.$ Now $p=1$ for $x=0,$ hence $f(x)=1-x.$

Comment: @StubbornAtom we can further assume that $c=1/2$, because of the symmetry. Infinite such functions are possible, so you can't really say anything based on that alone

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Let

$$ I = \int_0^1 (x - f(x))^{2016}\, dx $$

Substitute $ x = f(u) $ and note that $ f(0) = 1 $, $ f(1) = 0 $ to obtain

$$ I = \int_1^0 (f(u) - u)^{2016} f'(u)\, du = - \int_0^1 (x - f(x))^{2016} f'(x)\, dx $$

Then,

$$ 2I = I + I = \int_{0}^{1} (x - f(x))^{2016} (1 - f'(x))\, dx $$

and we may substitute $ w = x - f(x) $, $ dw = (1 - f'(x))\, dx $ (noting that $1 - f(1) = 1 $ and $ 0 - f(0) = -1 $) to obtain

$$ 2I = \int_{-1}^{1} w^{2016}\, dw = \frac{2}{2017} $$

and

$$ I = \int_0^1 (x - f(x))^{2016}\, dx = \frac{1}{2017} $$

Comment: Why are you so quick at typing? I had been typing this. Well, doesn't matter. +1.

Comment: It must be my lucky day today :)

Comment: So we need not know what $f(x)$ is in this solution. But I was wondering if for every real number $k>0$, $f(x) = \displaystyle\left(1-x^{\frac{1}{k}}\right)^k$ satisfies all conditions in the problem.

Comment: @adityagupta $ f $ is its own inverse.

Comment: @EgeErdil Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to note that $f(f(x))=x$ means that $f(x)$ is its own inverse. Geometrically, this means that the function will be perpendicular to the line $y=x$ at the point of intersection and symmetric on each side of $y=x$. Since it is differentiable over $[0,1]$ and we are given that $f(0)=1$, one such function that comes to mind is $f(x)=1-x$.

Now that a possible function is known, the calculation of the integral is easy:

$$\int_0^1 (x-f(x))^{2016}\,dx=\int_0^1(2x-1)^{2016}\,dx=\frac{1}{2017}$$

Comment: Yes, but you have to show that the value of the integral is the same for *all* such functions, which makes this solution invalid. (Unless you are in a multiple choice test, then it is clearly the superior solution :))

Comment: That is correct, my solution does not show that $\frac{1}{2017}$ is the value of the integral in all such cases. It is purely here to give an explicit example for the OP if he is interested in such an example.

Comment: I was so close to solving this question.... I kept on trying with $x-1$ and thinking it seems right... but won't satisfy the condition. *facepalm* from my side.

Comment: @Starfall Unfortunately this was not a multiple choice question.

Answer (score 0):

Fix a positive even natural $\text{n}$ (we care about the case in which $\text{n}=2016$, but the argument is general).

As $f\left(x\right)$ is continuous and injective, $f\left(x\right)-x$ must be monotonically decreasing with a unique root on $\left[0,1\right]$. It follows that $$0\ \leq\ \left(f\left(x\right)-x\right)^{\text{n}}\ \leq\ 1$$ for $x\in\left[0,1\right]$ and also that for any $y\in\left[0,1\right]$ there exists a (unique, continuous) choice of $\alpha\left(y\right),\beta\left(y\right)\in\left[0,1\right]$ such that $$\left(f\left(x\right)-x\right)^{\text{n}}\leq y\ \iff\ x\in\left[\alpha\left(y\right),\beta\left(y\right)\right]\text{.}$$ In particular, $\alpha\left(y\right)$ and $\beta\left(y\right)$ are the unique values satisfying $$f\left(\alpha\left(y\right)\right)-\alpha\left(y\right)\ =\ \sqrt[n]{y}$$ $$\beta\left(y\right)-f\left(\beta\left(y\right)\right)\ =\ \sqrt[n]{y}\text{,}$$ so that $$\beta\left(y\right)=f\left(\alpha\left(y\right)\right)\ \implies\ \beta\left(y\right)-\alpha\left(y\right)\ =\ \sqrt[n]{y}\text{.}$$ We conclude that
\begin{align*}
    \int_{x=0}^{1} \left(f\left(x\right)-x\right)^{\text{n}}\ \text{d}x\ &=\ 1-\int_{y=0}^{1} \left(\beta\left(y\right)-\alpha\left(y\right)\right)\ \text{d}y\\
    &=\ 1-\int_{y=0}^{1} \sqrt[n]{y}\ \text{d}y\\
    &=\ \int_{x=0}^{1} x^{n}\ \text{d}x\\
    &=\ \boxed{\tfrac{1}{n+1}}\text{.}
\end{align*}
(Note that we did not need the hypothesis that $f$ is differentiable—continuity suffices!)

Comment: (Note also that essentially the above argument shows more generally that $\int_{x=0}^{1} g\left(f\left(x\right)-x\right)\text{d}x=\int_{x=0}^{1} g\left(x\right)\text{d}x$ for $g\colon\left[-1,1\right]\to\mathbb{R}$ an even continuous function satisfying $g\left(0\right)=0$ and with $g\colon\left[0,1\right]\to\mathbb{R}$ injective.)